# When undoing a git rebase with reflog, does it matter which commit you choose?

Tags: eclipse, git, rebase

I know what the commit was (b7104e0) for my feature branch (GL18) before I attempted a rebase, which went poorly.  I'm looking through Git Reflog in Eclipse and it lists the commit b7104e0 several times.  I want to reset the head of GL18 back to b7104e0.  Does it matter which b7104e0 commit I choose in reflog on which to reset, or it is all the same?

Comment: If your rebase failed, you can also run `git rebase --abort` instead of `git reset` in order to get to the old state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A git hash is computed using the commit message, commit author, commit date, the tree hash, and all parent commit hashes, see [this blog post on the anatomy of a Git commit](http://blog.thoughtram.io/git/2014/11/18/the-anatomy-of-a-git-commit.html) for details.

This means every commit you see with the same hash is the exact same commit. You can use any of these. In fact, if you reset, you reset to the commit hash: `git reset --hard b7104e0`.

Answer (score 2):

No–but just for clarity, since the headline and body text seem at first to ask different questions, let's spell it out explicitly here:

- The "true name" of any commit (or indeed any repository object in git) is its SHA-1, which in this case starts with `b7104e0` (but goes on for another 33 characters).  This true-name uniquely identifies the object.  It can be abbreviated to something shorter, as in this case, as long as the shorter version remains unique.
- All other names, such as branch names, tags, the very special ref `HEAD`, the slightly less special (but still special) `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, and so on, and (**finally** :-) ) reflog entries like `HEAD@{3}` or `branchname@{1}`, are just ways to express the "true name" SHA-1 ID.  There's a special exemption to this rule when using `git checkout` or a command that rewrites a reference name, but in general, a name or reflog entry just resolves to the ID.  Many names may resolve to a single ID, or perhaps only one name resolves to the ID, but the names do resolve to IDs, in general.<sup>1</sup>

Once you have the correct ID, it does not matter how you got it.

---

<sup>1</sup>Just for completeness: it's obvious that if we're going to *change* the target SHA-1 ID of a name, e.g., to move a branch or write a new value into `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, we need the name, not its current ID.  The other place we need a name is when using an *indirect* ("symbolic") reference, such as when `HEAD` names `ref: refs/heads/master` so that you're `on branch master` as `git status` will put it.

We also have one special case where a name does not resolve to any SHA-1 ID, and that's the "branch yet to be born" one, which is most common in a new repository with no commits at all: in this case, you're on branch `master`, but `refs/heads/master` cannot resolve to a commit ID as there are no commits yet.  This special case can recur later if you use `git checkout --orphan` to create a new branch that does not (yet) point to any SHA-1 (it will acquire its initial SHA-1 on the next commit).  In these two oddball cases, the `HEAD` reference exists but names a branch that literally *does not* exist (yet).